# How many skips are there in this melody

Tags: intervals

The text says there are 12 skips (intervals that are larger than 2 semitones) in this folk song. I counted it several times, and I see 13 skips, not 12. It's from a highly reputed journal; and also, I'm a highly sceptic person. How many skips are there in this melody?

The melody: https://ibb.co/DV6TtR8

Comment: I count 13 as well. But I’m guessing maybe the skip between the second and third bars of the second line isn’t counted, because it happens between the end of one phrase and the start of another.

Comment: @BobBroadley It's the same sor the 1st and the 2nd bar too. I don't think this is the reason

Comment: Anyone have an offline copy?  The link is no longer active

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an error in the article. There are 13 "skips" of which 11 immediately change direction. The two exceptions are m. 1, beats 2 and 3, which is followed by a repeated note, and m. 5, beats 2 and 3, which is followed by another leap in the same direction.

Comment: It seems to be. However it s hard to belive that they didn't notice it.